# How to use ssh to login to an embedded ubuntu server

Tags: php, ssh

I've been using Python to get most of the things done that I want to accomplish. But, to broaden my horizons, I'm making an attempt to learn PHP as well. How can I ssh into an ubuntu server using php? Below is a few lines of code (form that ask user for ip address):

```
 <form name="form1" method="post" action="connect.php">
 <label>Connect:
 <input type="text" name="connect" onclick="this.value='';" onfocus="this.select()" onblur="this.value=!this.value?'Enter IP Address To Connect':this.value;" value="Enter IP Address To Connect"/>
  </label>
  <label>
  <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"/>
  </label>
</form>
```

Also, is there something that can be displayed to let the user know that he/she is logged in (eg... connected: green radio button; disconnected: red radio button)? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Kounavi - not all hosts let you do exec() or system() or whatever.

My recommendation would be to use [phpseclib, a pure PHP SSH implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/).  Example:

```
<?php
include('Net/SSH2.php');

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('www.domain.tld');
if (!$ssh->login('username', 'password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

echo $ssh->exec('pwd');
echo $ssh->exec('cd /');
echo $ssh->exec('pwd');
?>
```

Comment: Yes, but you can ssh (which is exactly the point of the question here). Whether you can exec/system or do anything else in the host machine lies entirely on your rights granted by the admin responsible for the referred machine. If he wants to send commands remotely he may use the expect utility if he wants to (automated installations/terminal commands etc) or he/she may follow your advice ;) :) xD

Answer (score 1):

Read something about [SSH in PHP](http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/make_ssh_connections_with_php/)

Comment: I will, at home this weekend ... just looking for something quick and dirty to get me started while at work ... very smart answer genius, oops I meant genesis. Thanks!

Comment: helped ... ? Let's say enlightened me about some on this site .... not in my question.

Answer (score 1):

Why not ssh with bash?
It's pretty easy and you'll get up and running in no time! Unless your program does not need to be run on Windows (or any other flavor that is non-*Nix) try to write -portable- bash code.

P.S.:SSH-ing tasks will be much easier if you automate them with an ssh repository(i.e:ssh-agent using ssh-add) ;)